# Не прибавляются числа к эспоненте (числу е) в большой степени. C#

Tags: c#

Допустим на напишу

```
1 + Math.E;
```

Получится 3.71828182845905

Если я напишу так

```
1 + Math.Pow(Math.E, 2);
```

Выведет 8.38905609893065 - правильно все

Но если я напишу

```
1 + Math.Pow(Math.E, 59);
```

Будет 4.2012104037905E+25 как если бы я написал просто `Math.Pow(Math.E, 59);`

Если писать `1 + Math.Exp(59)` - выходит – то же самое.
В чем проблема и как тогда их сложить?

P.S.: мне это нужно для формулы сигмоиды: `1d / (1d + Math.Exp(-x))` где x любое число. Нужно что бы все числа уравнивались так что бы были от 0 до 1.

Comment: Почитайте про 1) Эспоненциальное представление числа 2) Точность чисел с плавающей точкой

Comment: Прибавление единички к 25-значному числу не даст эффекта, так как точность double не позволит, а чего именно вы хотите достичь? Какую задачу решаете? Какой результат ожидаемый для вас?

Comment: @aepot нужна формула сигмоиды для C#, что бы можно было подставлять в неё значения x

Comment: Так `-x` зачем вам вычислять функцию от `-59`? Какой диапазон `x` вам нужен? К тому же если вы разделите единицу на то самое огромное число, вы получите очень близкое к нулю значение, к которому прибавление в знаменателе единички погоды совсем не сделает. Другими словами, у вас все в порядке.

Comment: Вопрос вызван проблемой, которая больше не воспроизводится, или опечаткой. Хотя похожие вопросы могут быть уместны на этом сайте, решение для этого вопроса вряд ли поможет будущим посетителям. Обычно можно избежать подобных вопросов написанием и исследованием [минимальной программы для воспроизведения проблемы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) до публикации вопроса.

Comment: @aepot диапазон может быть любой от -бесконечности до +. Мне нужна сигмода как функция которая выравнивает значения нейро-сети, что бы были все они от 0 до 1. А -59 это просто то число в дебаге которое выдал один нейрон и поэтому на его примере я пытаюсь починить функицю.

Comment: При больших значениях X эта единичка будет в рамках погрешности. Вам нужно просто задать комфортный диавазон, при котором функция даст вам комфортные значения, потому что за рамками этого диапазона, она будет просто стремиться к асимптоте.

Comment: @aepot т.е. записать например `if (x>10) {result = 0} else if (x < -10) {result = 1} else {result = 1d/(1d+Math.Exp(-x))}` Я правильно понял?

Comment: Именно так. Но вы можете перепроверить опытным путем, устраивает ли вас имеющаяся точность вычислений.